# What is the purpose of lock the login keychain?

Tags: macos, password, keychain

This is what I mean:

[image]

When I try to lock above keychain I get a lot of pop alerts similar to this:

`accountsd wants to use the login keychain`, `"safari wants to use the login keychain"` and so on. If such thing produces a lot of annoying alerts, so **what is the reason to lock login keychain**? **Should it be unlocked usually?**

Comment: It's normal unlocked whilst that user is using it... otherwise each access requires authority.

Comment: @Tetsujin are you sure? even for read-only? Could you please add an answer then ?

Comment: I'm not certain enough to turn it into an answer. I have no documentary evidence, just empirical.